# I want to add underscores to this email pattern code in html form

Tags: html, forms, email, design-patterns

I am trying to accept a valid email address, and I researched and found you can have underscores _ in the domain and my code doesn't accept that.

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$
```

for my input type="email"

I tried adding an _ in one place at a time after the first section and I can't figure it out. All I want to do is to be able to add multiple non-consecutive underscores in the domain name section of the pattern.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

From what I am able to understand

To allow underscores (_) in the domain section of the email address, you can modify the regular expression pattern as follows:

```
pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$"
```

In this modified pattern, I **replaced [a-zA-Z0-9-] with [a-zA-Z0-9_-]** within **the domain section.** This change allows both hyphens (-) and underscores (_) in the domain name.

**Note** that the underscore (_) is a valid character for the domain part of an email address according to the email address specification. However, some email providers may have specific restrictions or limitations on the use of underscores, so make sure to check it.

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: thanks man but that didn't work either. it still won't accept underscores.

Comment: ok, that pattern you gave does work after I changed the type from email to text! Thanks! Now is there any way you can help me from allowing consecutive _ and . before the @ in the email? I am pretty sure you can't make emails with two consecutive _ or . in it. Or can you? Thanks again Bhavesh!! :-)

Comment: Thanks, but now is there any way you can change the pattern to prevent consecutive _ and . before the @ in the email? I am pretty sure you can't make emails with two consecutive _ or . in it. Or can you? I just need to know.

Comment: I have decided to find an alternate method. I want to use javascript to force a proper email if anyone has a script for me. Thank you for everything!